# How to store php variable content in HTML "id"

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have 3 variables in PHP, message_id, message_title, message_content. I store the content of those variables inside HTML 'id' so that I can use them later with jQuery.

Like this:

Varibles:

```
$id_variable = $rows['id_mensagem'];
$message_title_edit = $rows['title_text'];
$message_content_edit = $rows['txt_mensagem'];
```

Here's the "ids" part.

```
 echo '<a href="#" class="edit_message" id='.$id_variable.' message='.$message_content_edit.' titulo ='.$message_title_edit .' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#open_modal_edit">Detalhes </a>';
```

How you can see, `id=$id_variable`, `message = $message_content_edit`, `titulo = $message_title_edit`

Where's my problem:

The Id message & titulo store data inside untill first blank space.

Like this:

```
$id_variable = '10';
$message_title_edit = 'Just some title';
$message_content_edit = 'Some content';
```

echo/Output:

```
echo '<a href="#" class="edit_message" id='10' message='Just' titulo ='Some' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#open_modal_edit">Detalhes </a>';
```

[image: Image of what's happening]

Comment: Not a very clear question.  What do you mean by "how can you see"?  Seems like some PHP generated javascript on the page could clean things up a bit.  Adding all those custom attributes to an anchor is rather strange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you never print any quotes.

```
echo '<a href="#" class="edit_message" id='.$id_variable.' message='.$message_content_edit.' titulo ='.$message_title_edit .' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#open_modal_edit">Detalhes </a>';
```

Will *actually* evaluate to

```
<a href="#" class="edit_message" id=10 message=Some content titulo=Just some title data-toggle="modal" data-target="#open_modal_edit">Detalhes </a>
```

Which IS NOT valid HTML, so the browser / interpreter does its bet to try and guess what you meant.

You need to add quotes to your printout

```
echo '<a href="#" class="edit_message" id="'.$id_variable.'" message="'.$message_content_edit.'" titulo ="'.$message_title_edit .'" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#open_modal_edit">Detalhes </a>';
```

Comment: Thank you. These simple things...

Answer (score 0):

You need to quote them correctly, try:

```
 echo '<a href="#" class="edit_message" id="'.$id_variable.'" message="'.$message_content_edit.'" titulo ="'.$message_title_edit .'" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#open_modal_edit">Detalhes </a>';
```

Comment: Yes, this solved my problem, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add "" around the values and titulo has a space before the equals.

It also looks like you may have some message information in the variables so it maybe worth html encoding the variables before output so that if $message_content_edit contains a " then it won't break the HTML e.g.

```
echo '<a href="#" class="edit_message" id="' . $id_variable . '" message="' . htmlspecialchars($message_content_edit) . '" titulo="' . htmlspecialchars($message_title_edit) . '" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#open_modal_edit">Detalhes </a>';
```